# fetch a field'API value using SOQL in javascript

Tags: visualforce, soql, javascript

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/soap/ajax/33.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/soap/ajax/33.0/apex.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">  

 function soqlQuery(){          
      try{
          var currentRecId="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.Id}";
          console.log(currentRecId);
          var result = sforce.connection.query("SELECT StageName FROM Opportunity WHERE Id:currentRecId",{
              onSuccess : function(result){
                  alert('Get the stagename');
                  console.log(result);
              },
              onFailure : function(error){
                    alert('No');
              }
          });
      }catch(e){
          alert(e);
      }
  }
  window.onload=function(){
      soqlQuery();
  }
 </script>
```

I try to fetch one field value (stageName) from Opportunity sobject using currentPage's record Id.
But This will return "No(alert)"

How can i solve it?  Also I prefer to fetch API name ...not field label name

Here is the screenshots from Chrome's Developer console (console and network tabs)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post errors from Chrome's Developer console (network tabs) to help us out.

Comment: I uploaded screenshots
Please check it

Comment: What message are you getting from the `error` parameter that is passed to the onFailure method?

Comment: Im sorry I dont understand you. After I saved this VF, I got " No" which is from the onFailure method.
What I expect is to get "'Get the stagename'" which is from the onSuccess method

Comment: @KazuSuzuki You have `onFailure : function(error){ alert('No'); }`. Instead of alerting 'No', instead output what is in error, like `onFailure : function(error){ alert(error); }` You may need to check other parameters on the error object to see that actual error message.

Comment: @KazuSuzuki click on row that has error 500 (43.0, innitiator connetion.js). You'll find your error description there in response subtab.

Comment: you're missing = in your SOQL - you have WHERE Id: ... not WHERE Id =: .... If you copy pasted that to this page - try fixing that first. then see if you're fixed up. @KazuSuzuki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">  ***sforce.connection.sessionId='{!GETSESSIONID()}'***;function soqlQuery(){          
  try{
      var currentRecId="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.Id}";
      console.log(currentRecId);

      var result = sforce.connection.query("SELECT StageName FROM Opportunity WHERE Id =\'"+currentRecId+"\'" ,{
          onSuccess : function(result){
              alert('Get the stagename');
              console.log(result);
          },
          onFailure : function(error){
                alert('No');
          }
      });
  }catch(e){
      alert(e);
  }  window.onload=function(){
  soqlQuery();}</script>
```

@dzh Thank you very much I checked 500 (43.0, innitiator connetion.js). Then I understand one of problems was about sessionId.

And one more problem was about SOQL.

Answer (score 0):

Use this way..

```
var currentRecId="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.Id}";

var result = sforce.connection.query("SELECT StageName FROM Opportunity WHERE Id='" + currentRecId +"'",{....
```

Comment: I tried but it doesnt work

Comment: Check the single quote

Comment: i tried it  but it doesnt work too